# Convert point cloud to voxels via averaging

Tags: matlab, histogram

I have the following data:

```
N = 10^3;
x = randn(N,1);
y = randn(N,1);
z = randn(N,1);
f = x.^2+y.^2+z.^2;
```

Now I want to split this continuous 3D space into `nB` bins.

```
nB = 20;
[~,~,x_bins] = histcounts(x,nB);
[~,~,y_bins] = histcounts(y,nB);
[~,~,z_bins] = histcounts(z,nB);
```

And put in each cube average `f` or `nan` if no observations happen in the cube:

```
F = nan(50,50,50);

for iX = 1:20
    for iY = 1:20
        for iZ = 1:20
            idx = (x_bins==iX)&(y_bins==iY)&(z_bins==iZ);
            F(iX,iY,iZ) = mean(f(idx));
        end
    end
end
isosurface(F,0.5)
```

This code does what I want. My problem is the speed. This code is extremely slow when `N > 10^5` and `nB = 100`.

How can I speed up this code?

---

I also tried the `accumarray()` function:

```
subs=([x_bins,y_bins,z_bins]);
F2 = accumarray(subs,f,[],@mean);
all(F(:) == F2(:)) % false
```

However, this code produces a different result.

Comment: @Wick Thank you, but it seems I do something wrong (see update)

Comment: `accumarray` produces the same result. When a bin contains no point the loop solution produces `nan` but `accumarray` produces `0` .

Comment: @zlon Your modified code works. But there are two problems with it. First, the elements that didn't increment are still 0. You can set them to NaN with `F2(F2==0)=NaN;` Secondly, `NaN == NaN` always comes back as false. So using `all` to compare the two matrices will still come back as zero. If you just try to compare the numerical elements of F and F2 you'll find they're not exactly the same either - they're off by 10^-14 or so. Those are rounding errors in the FP calcs. Well done taking a suggestion and finding the solution with it.

Comment: For each bin you test all elements in your point cloud. This is a lot of work! Instead, invert the logic: loop over your points and find the bin that each one corresponds to. You then need to keep two accumulation arrays: one for the sum and one for the count. At the end of the loop, divide the one by the other. You automatically get NaNs where you divide 0/0 where there were no points.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem with the code in the OP is that it tests all elements of the data for each element in the output array. The output array has `nB^3` elements, the data has `N` elements, so the algorithm is O(`N*nB^3`). Instead, one can loop over the `N` elements of the input, and set the corresponding element in the output array, which is an operation O(`N`) (2nd code block below).

The `accumarray` solution in the OP needs to use the `fillvals` parameter, set it to `NaN` (3rd code block below).

To compare the results, one needs to explicitly test that both arrays have `NaN` in the same locations, and have equal non-NaN values elsewhere:

```matlab
all( ( isnan(F(:)) & isnan(F2(:)) ) | ( F(:) == F2(:) ) )
%    \-------same NaN values------/   \--same values--/
```

Here is code. All three versions produce identical results. Timings in Octave 4.4.1 (no JIT), in MATLAB the loop code should be faster. (Using input data from OP, with `N=10^3` and `nB=20`).

```matlab
%% OP's code, O(N*nB^3)
tic
F = nan(nB,nB,nB);
for iX = 1:nB
    for iY = 1:nB
        for iZ = 1:nB
            idx = (x_bins==iX)&(y_bins==iY)&(z_bins==iZ);
            F(iX,iY,iZ) = mean(f(idx));
        end
    end
end
toc
% Elapsed time is 1.61736 seconds.

%% Looping over input, O(N)
tic
s = zeros(nB,nB,nB);
c = zeros(nB,nB,nB);
ind = sub2ind([nB,nB,nB],x_bins,y_bins,z_bins);
for ii=1:N
   s(ind(ii)) = s(ind(ii)) + f(ii);
   c(ind(ii)) = c(ind(ii)) + 1;
end
F2 = s ./ c;
toc
% Elapsed time is 0.0606539 seconds.

%% Other alternative, using accumarray
tic
ind = sub2ind([nB,nB,nB],x_bins,y_bins,z_bins);
F3 = accumarray(ind,f,[nB,nB,nB],@mean,NaN);
toc
% Elapsed time is 0.14113 seconds.
```